# MySQL (MariaDB) memory calculation andusage creep

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have used the mysql memory calculator (http://www.mysqlcalculator.com) to estimate the memory usage of my dedicated mysql server with 8GB ram and 4CPUs.

These are the actual figures and the calculation of my usage:

```
binlog_cache_size                   32.00 KB
innodb_buffer_pool_size             5120.00 MB
innodb_log_buffer_size              8.00 MB
join_buffer_size                    1.00 MB
key_buffer_size                     128.00 MB
max_connections                     150
query_cache_size                    0
read_buffer_size                    128.00 KB
read_rnd_buffer_size                256.00 KB
sort_buffer_size                    2.00 MB
thread_stack                        292.00 KB
tmp_table_size                      32.00 MB
=================================== ==========
Total Max Memory                    5841.73 MB
=================================== ==========
```

Over a period of a week, the memory just keeps increasing way beyond the estimated calculations until it consumes pretty much all of the 8GB and never drops back until the engine is restarted.

So my guess is that there is some variable which is omitted from the calculation that is resulting in this over-usage.

Any suggestions on what I can do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there appears to be an error with that calculator (http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/) .

```
tmp_table_size
```

Should be included in the per-connection calculations and not in the base-memory calculations.

The base-memory variables are those that are listed above the max_connections, and the per-connection variables are listed below.

This made a huge difference to the calculation and the reason why the actual usage did not match the calculations.

This is courtesy of: [@Christopher Schultz](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-use.html)

```
SELECT ( @@key_buffer_size
+ @@query_cache_size
+ @@innodb_buffer_pool_size
+ @@innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
+ @@innodb_log_buffer_size
+ @@max_connections * ( @@read_buffer_size
+ @@read_rnd_buffer_size
+ @@sort_buffer_size
+ @@join_buffer_size
+ @@binlog_cache_size
+ @@thread_stack
+ @@tmp_table_size )
) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;
```

Answer (score -2):

mysqlcalculator.com unfortunately overlooks some important settings. And the other answer isn't quite complete. This is from a handy [MySQL/MariaDB tuning article](https://shatteredsilicon.net/mariadb-performance-tuning-and-mysql-performance-tuning/):

```
SELECT (
       (
           @@binlog_file_cache_size +
           @@innodb_buffer_pool_size +
           @@innodb_log_buffer_size +
           @@key_buffer_size +
           @@query_cache_size +
           ( @@max_connections *
               ( @@binlog_cache_size +
                 @@binlog_stmt_cache_size +
                 @@bulk_insert_buffer_size +
                 @@join_buffer_size +
                 @@max_allowed_packet +
                 @@read_buffer_size +
                 @@read_rnd_buffer_size +
                 @@sort_buffer_size +
                 @@thread_stack +
                 @@tmp_table_size
               )
           ) +
           ( @@slave_parallel_threads * 
             ( @@slave_parallel_max_queued )
           ) +
           ( @@open_files_limit * 1024)
       ) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS max_memory_GB;
```

Adjust these settings until everything fits into your RAM.

Disclosure: I wrote the referenced article.

Comment: Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)